# Widget Exception on Power On

Tags: android

My app has a home screen widget. When I power on the phone (from off, not sleep) I get a fatal exception.

```
04-06 14:33:59.739: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.mytest.myapp.AppWidget: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mytest.myapp.AppWidget in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mytest.myapp-2.apk]

04-06 14:33:59.832: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(269): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mytest.myapp.AppWidget in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.mytest.myapp-2.apk]
```

If I click the app to start it again, it works fine. Any idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see the Manifest.mf, just in case there's a typo lurking in there.

Failing that, the only explanation that leaps to mind is that the phone is trying to launch the app before /data is mounted. Can you reproduce in the emulator?

Phil Lello

Comment: That error is from the emulator. When I say power on from off, I mean starting the emulator. It doesn't seem to have that problem on my actual phone. But it's concerning that the emulator does.

Comment: Hmm. I generally find the emulator is unusably slow, so go with on-device debugging. My gut reaction is that this is probably an issue with emulator performance.